# Location of pip after removing anaconda?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I've used pip multiple times, but ever since I removed the anaconda package, I can't seem to figure out how to use pip.

Whenever doing `pip install <name>`, I get the message:

```
-bash: /Users/myusername/anaconda/bin/pip: No such file or directory
```

I did `sudo easy_install pip`, which seems to have ran correctly, but I still receive the same error whenever trying to install a package.

Anyone know a fix to get my comp to find the correct location of pip?

Comment: What gives you `which pip`? Your pip binary may be linked to an erased one. You may want to remove this link. If `pip` then gives you "command unfound", try to reinstall pip, and make sure the installed binary is in your path.

Comment: what OS are you using?